# Rejected emails when sending from google apps to some domains (550 Unrouteable address/Sender verify failed)

Tags: email, g-suite, email-bounces

i'm sending emails from my domain prokubo.com using google apps and
i'm having returned emails at least when sendind to two different domains:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     paulo.sousa@centralaccount.pt

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient     domain centralaccount.pt  by mail-pt.securemail.pro . [81.88.48.101].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-Verification failed for <info@prokubo.com>
550-Unrouteable address
550 Sender verify failed
```

and also

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     mesas@coworklisboa.pt

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient         domain coworklisboa.pt by mx1.coworklisboa.pt . [81.88.48.104].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-Verification failed for <info@prokubo.com>
550-Unrouteable address
550 Sender verify failed
```

is this something I can fix? i did not have the spf record, now, i added it, but the same thing keeps happening :(

Comment: Try changing your SPF record to "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com mx ~all"

Comment: ok, i added "mx" that was the only thing missing... do I have to wait to test if it is working?

Comment: Probably, but give it a try, just checked your DNS and the change seems done.

Comment: nop... i get the same error :(

Comment: Can you try sending an email to "admin@uniagro.com" ? I'll check my SMTP server and see why it is rejecting.

Comment: Yes, i have done so. (it did not bounce from your email, but i hope you still can check anything :) - thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21671/discussion-between-ojovirtual-and-tiago-coelho).